# what is the best way to integrate wordpress subdirectory with joomla website?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Sorry for the trouble. I just want to ask is there a way to integrate wordpress subdirectory into joomla website? What i am trying to do is develop a blog site with wordpress subdirectory in joomla's corporate site and everytime that i post an article in wordpress it will display in root joomla website's template. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Simply installing WordPress in a subdirectory of a Joomla site will not automatically display WordPress posts in the Joomla template.

You could develop a WordPress template that matches the Joomla one, or consider a Joomla integrated solution like https://www.corephp.com/joomla-products/wordpress-for-joomla

For what it's worth, it is fairly easy to blog within Joomla. You might consider looking at your specific needs and they to accomplish everything from within Jomla.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have decided to learn to blog with Joomla. Thanks.

Comment: That's great news! Glad I was able to help.

Comment: @MRu there is nothing to learn Joomla. If you're new to CMS, then start with Blogger->Wordpress->Joomla..

Answer (score 1):

In the terms of usability & user friendliness having just one platform is the best solution.
There are plenty of joomla! Blog extensions available in JED directory and, I am sure you will find the most appropriate.
By the way, here is a FREE tool called [WordPress to JoomBlog converter](http://www.joomplace.com/free-joomla-extensions/wordpress-to-joomblog-converter.html), that allows migration, saving all the users, categories and blog comments. Just to let you know